# Why a for loop isn't considered 'stylish' by my teachers?

Tags: c

I had to write a piece of code which would search a given value in an array.
I made this piece of code, which works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int index_van(int searchedValue, int array[], int lengthArray)
{
    int i ;
    for (i = 0; i < lengthArray; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == searchedValue)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;    
}

int main()
{
    int array2 [] = {0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2};
    printf("%i", index_van(2, array2, 6));
}
```

With the correction (the teacher put up online) of this exercise the notes of my teacher were:
You have to quit the moment you have found your value ,so you can't search through the entire table if you have found your value already. A for-loop therefore isn't tolerated.
Even if the for-loop has an extra built-in condition, THIS ISN'T STYLISH!

// One small note ,she was talking in general . She hasn't seen my version of the exercise.

So my question to you guys is, is my code really 'not done' towards professionalism and 'style' ?

Comment: Your code is excellent (apart from its dire indentation which shows no style at all). It is absolutely how I would write it. If your teacher doesn't like it, then your teacher needs to get out a bit more.

Comment: I wonder how stylish your teacher really is. And what kind of stylish friends she has.

Comment: She's a snob.  A `return` out of a `for` loop is not generally wise, but a `break` works just as well in most cases.

Comment: I vote for pita. This code is just fine, imho, modulo some weird spacing.

Comment: @HotLicks : What do you mean? Why is a return not as good as a break? :)

Comment: @Max : Care to elaborate? :)

Comment: A return is way better here. This is a function that does not mutate state. It's sole job is to return a value. Once the value is known it must return ASAP. End of story. Using break here would be a travesty.

Comment: Your code is fine. Your formatting is wild though.

Comment: @ Boann : What do you mean ? I'm pretty new to programming ? :)

Comment: @BURNS - A return from a loop has a tendency to, uh, burn you.  Not in such a simple case, but "enhance" it a few times and the fact that there's a return there can be lost in the weeds.  Defensive programming -- expect your code to be edited.

Comment: It is worth noting that one could use a `while` loop and have an equally nice overall design -- probably no better, but equally good.  Maybe for extra credit you should turn in BOTH designs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: How would a good indentation look like? :)

Comment: @HotLicks If you served up a linear search that used `break` instead of `return`, my code review would reject it. It is dogmatic to say that "break is better than return". Sometimes break is better. Sometimes return is better. I loathe dogma. Use the right tool for the job. Don't try to use the same tool all the time. Have you ever tried drilling a hole with a hammer?

Comment: @BURNS Look in any text book to find out.

Comment: The asker did mention that the teacher made a general statement not actually referring to the asker's code. I'd actually prefer a while/do-while here, but still give points for a for-loop.

Comment: I agree with the comments in support of your code BURNS, but in defence of your teacher's opinion: the goal of the loop is to find a match, not to search the entire array. I think she wants you to reverse the priority of checks. The check-for-match placed in the control statement of the loop itself better indicates what you're trying to accomplish. In this case the difference is trivial, but I say she has a point in general.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a for loop, and return inside a for loop is perfectly normal. I would have written the code the same way, although I might have chosen different names for the arguments, and used size_t for the type of the array length.

Comment: I would say that your teacher doesn't really know too much C. She may think that you can use `for` loops just to iterate over a range. Maybe she knows that `for` is mostly syntactic sugar for a `while` loop but has decided that your mind would not accept so much knowledge and so, she is teaching you a subset of C... it would be equally wrong!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I've been programming for 40 years.  I loathe bugs.

Comment: @Hot So presumably you hate dogma too

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Well actually, catmas more than dogmas.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think she's implying that you should use a `while` loop because you don't know how many iterations it will take to get you what you're looking for.  It may be an issue of her wanting you to understand the difference of when to use `for` and `while` loops.

**"...Even if the for-loop has an extra built-in condition..."**

I think this right here explains her intentions.  A `for` loop would need a built-in condition to exit once it's found what it's looking for.  a `while` loop already is required to have the condition.

Comment: I'd add that in this case a while loop is a bit easier to read- it makes it clear from the beginning what the termination condition is.  Instead a for loop sets up an expectation in the reader's mind that you want to loop a fixed number of times and then suddenly we see there's another termination condition.  I've worked places where you'd be coached into using the while statement in this case...

Comment: I'd coach away from a while loop!

Comment: Why he cannot use `for(;;)` instead `while`?

Comment: @haccks If you read the entire discussion, you'll see that everyone says his code is fine, it's just his teacher wanted him to implement it differently for learning purposes

Comment: @peeskillet; No. I did't mean that. You said: `A for loop would need a built-in condition to exit once it's found what it's looking for. a while loop already is required to have the condition` , I think using `for` without any expression, i.e, `for(;;) will work in similar way.

Comment: @haccks it will work similarly.  But the teacher wants him to explore the difference of when to use the different loops.  `while` loops should be used when you don't know how many iterations you need.  The reason a `for` loop wouldn't be efficient without a condition s because it will have to iterate the through the entire loop.

Comment: @peeskillet; And that's what I am trying to say that it is a myth!

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing wrong with your code. I have no idea if using a for loop is less stylish than using another, but stylish is a very subjective attribute.

That being said, don't go to your teacher and tell her this. Do what she says, a matter like this is not worth contradicting your teacher for. Most likely this is just a way to teach you how while loops work.

Comment: Let me add, that other people (myself included) write tons of `for` loops like yours, and consider it good style :-)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with politely asking why the teacher made the claim.

Answer (score 2):

After accept answer:

I've posted this to point out sometimes there is so much discussion of "style", that when a classic algorithmic improvement is at hand, it is ignored.

---

Normally a search should work with a `const` array and proceed as OP suggest using some loop that stops on 2 conditions: if the value was found or the entire array was searched.

```
int index_van(int searchedValue, const int array[], int lengthArray)
```

But *if* OP can get by with a non-`const` array, as posted, then the loop is *very* simple and faster.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int index_van(int searchedValue, int array[], int lengthArray) {
  if (lengthArray <= 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  int OldEnd = array[lengthArray - 1];
  // Set last value to match
  array[lengthArray - 1] = searchedValue;
  int i = 0;

  while (array[i] != searchedValue) i++;

  // Restore last value
  array[lengthArray - 1] = OldEnd;
  // If last value matched, was it due to the original array value?
  if (i == (lengthArray - 1)) {
    if (OldEnd != searchedValue) {
      return -1;
    }
  }
  return i;
}
```

BTW: Consider using `size_t` for `lengthArray`.